# How to correct my inorder traversal of a binary tree?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

So for the tree I'm working on, I can't figure out the Inorder Traversal. Currently I have:

4, 11, 9, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3, 2, 10

but this is incorrect. If anyone has an explanation of the correct answer, that would be helpful! I watched some videos for it but I have no idea what went wrong.

[image]

I tried:

4, 11, 9, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3, 2, 10

4, 11, 9, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3, 10, 2

both of these are incorrect, I'm not sure what to do with the long strand on the left or the order.

Comment: What do you mean by in-order given that your diagram is *not* a traditionally ordered binary search tree (for all nodes, left subtree values all less than current node, right subtree all greater)? How was the tree constructed in the first place?

Comment: The output can't start with 4 because both 9 and 11 are in order before 4. Some help [here](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/tree-traversal). You've indicated a number of incorrect outputs but what do you think the correct output should be?

Comment: [wiki:Tree traversal » In-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order,_LNR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "leftmost" node will be first in the inorder traversal.

One way to get a feel for this traversal order, is to draw the tree in such a way that every node ends up in its own, vertical column, such that below that node, that column is completely empty: no other nodes there, nor edges crossing that column. In other words, the nodes in a parent node's left sub tree should all be positioned more to the left than the parent node. Same thing for the nodes in its right sub tree: they should all be positioned more to the right.

For your example tree, that leads to this representation:

[image]

And now all that you have to do is read the node labels from left to right:

9 11 4 1 5 6 8 7 3 2 10

Answer (score 0):

In an in-order traversal, we recursively go through the nodes in the order **"ArB"**. In this notation **r** represents the current node while **A** and **B** are its left and right subtrees.

What it means is that we follow a simple algorithm:

1. Enter a new node
2. Process its left subtree
3. Process itself
4. Process its right subtree

After step 4, the sequence of visited nodes should look like this: 
`{nodes visited earlier}, {all of the left subtree nodes}, r, {all of right subtree nodes}`

###### In your specific case, do the following steps:

1. Start in node 6
2. Go to left child of 6 -> node 1 (processing left subtree)
3. Go to left child of 1 -> node 9 (processing left subtree)
4. Node 9 has no left child, we can treat it as already fully processed
5. We processed left child of 9, so we add the [9] to the sequence (process itself)
6. Go to right child of 9 -> 11 (process right subtree)
   ...

After fully processing the left subtree of 6 we should get `{9, 11, 4, 1, 5}`. Then you add `6` as its whole left subtree is already processed, and you can continue with its right subtree. Finally, the whole array looks like:
`{all of nodes in left subtree}, 6, {all of nodes in right subtree}`, which nicely corresponds to the previously mentioned **"ArB"** notation.

Comment: Thank you! I missed the left/ right part